# How to remove border around an image in html

Tags: html, css

I am displaying img elements using the following CSS.

```
.display-icon{
height: 16px;
width: 16px;
display:inline-block; 
border:hidden;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

In Internet Explorer, it works fine, but in Chrome, there is a border around the image. Is there any way to remove it? Unfortunately I could not use the src attribute in the img element as part of the company requirement.

Comment: Does  border:none; work that's what I've used.

Comment: `border:hidden` is an error. Try `border:none` or `border:0`. Also, I'm very curious as to what you mean by "I could not use the src attribute in the img element".

Comment: Post a complete code example please. A normal image with that class has no border. Is your image within a link?

Answer (score 0):

try `border:none` or `outline:none`?

Answer (score 0):

It can also be done like this

```
border-style:none;
```

Comment: I tried that too. Still the problem persists in Chrome!

Comment: the problem persist because your img tag has not an src attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
img.display-icon,
a img.display-icon { 
border: none;
}
```

to cover all eventualities.