# How to Remove Default Borders from a jpg image on webpage

Tags: html, css, image

[image: Screen Shot Here]

How can I remove these borders from image.

These borders are shown only with JPG image.

All other formats have no issue.

I Tried all of the below solutions

a img, :link img, :visited img {

border: 0;

}

a img, a:link img, a:visited img {

border:0 none;

}

none !Important;

0 !Important;

Also applied solution given in these below links
[How to remove border around an image in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33532120/how-to-remove-border-around-an-image-in-html/33532157)
https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/solved-remove-border-from-an-image/

Can any body help me solve this problem please

Comment: Does `img { border: none; }` work?

Comment: no, non of given solutions worked

Comment: It looks like the border is part of the image. Open the jpg with an image editor and check it

Comment: Going to ask the obvious since i've had this happen from our art department - are you sure the image itself wasn't cropped out completely to exclude that?

Comment: no its not part of the image, I created simple Full White image in paint, and tried. that has also these borders

Comment: can we see the full image path? Or is it from your machine?

Comment: @Brandon , I am not sure, what you mean. But I tried a lot of different images. when I convert the same image to png or wap, then it has no issue. even I opened paint, and Directly clicked on Save button , so that I can save full white image. that has also this problem

Comment: @Brandon , it is on localhost

Comment: @RiazKhan edit: got it okay nevermind. i just wanted to double check it

Comment: The border is part of the image, edit the image and remove the border.

Comment: @Grumpy Borders are not part of image. I ensured.

Answer (score -1):

Try giving **border:none;** command to the image in css if still doesn't work, you can have a check if you have given any padding to the image and there is a color to the padding it sometimes looks as a border. Hope this helps. Also have a look that the image itself may have a border and thus it is the original imagine that is being displayed

Comment: Nothing worked stuff like this. as mentioned in the Question.